# Migrating Javascript to TypeScript: Property doest exist on response

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I am trying to learn TS by converting an app to TS.

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

function someMiddleware(expressApp: 
  express.Application) {
 
  expressApp.use(function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
res.originalSendImplementation = res.send;
```

results in the error:

> Property 'originalSendImplementation' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'

Do I need an interface here?

Comment: can you write more code showing where you put the type and larger portion of the code ?

Comment: What request library is this? There is likely a way to tell the function what you expect the type to be by providing an interface to the generic, but it will vary between libraries.

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: You can use declaration merging for this: https://christiangiacomi.com/posts/extend-express-typescript-custom-types/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. @Bergi if you want to make it an answer I'll accept it. Otherwise, I'll add the answer for posterity.